# How does couchdb retrieve all previous revisions?

Tags: indexing, couchdb, b-tree

From what I understand, CouchDB's Btree implementation actually uses Shadowing technique, and every update will produce new root, the following excerpts from this [PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=B6555F332EBB2A35B1FDDAEEB12A316C?doi=10.1.1.161.6863&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (it looks like implementing a better algorithm than traditional shadowing).

> Shadowing means that to update an
>   on-disk page, the entire page is read
>   into memory, modified, and later
>   written to disk at an alternate
>   location. When a page is shadowed its
>   location on disk changes, this creates
>   a need to update (and shadow) the
>   immediate ancestor of the page with
>   the new address. Shadowing propagates
>   up to the file system root.

How does couchdb implement fetching all leaf revisions as possible as it can( since some revisions are removed by compacting process)? Does couch internally store a pointer which points to previous revisions?

Thanks
Chang

Comment: That is a tough question. Yes, Couch databases are roughly log-structured as you describe, but somehow the old leaf nodes must be referenced. I would like to know too. I will try to ask CouchDB developers, or tell them to answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By good luck, CouchDB committer and community leader Adam Kocoloski [explained this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201107.mbox/%3C939F7194-3FB2-44EA-8D1C-2CC4CE03248C@apache.org%3E) recently on the mailing list.

Here is what he said:

"Each leaf in the ID btree [stores] a revision tree containing pointers
to *all* available revisions of a document.  Retrieving an old revision (before compaction)
or a conflicting version of a document requires exactly the same number of IOs as retrieving
the current one."

If I understand correctly, shadowing is not used to conceal old document revisions at all, but rather *entire* revision trees that are no longer meaningful.

Comment: what is the meaning of 
"shadowing is not used to conceal old document revisions at all, but rather entire revision trees that are no longer meaningful"

Comment: It means, the leaf node of the btree is not a single document. It is exactly as you describe: the leaf node stores pointers to all (available) revisions.

Comment: @jsh if so, it should first load previous revision trees before update.

Comment: @Chang, yes it does that. There have been some complaints about performance for very large databases because of so many reads before a write. I believe that is currently a priority for the CouchDB development team.

Answer (score 6):

Couch doesn't guarantee that old revisions of a document can be retrieved:

> The terms version and revision might sound familiar (if you are programming
>   without version control, drop this book right now and start
>   learning one of the popular systems). Using new versions for document
>   changes works a lot like version control, but there’s an important difference:
>   CouchDB does not guarantee that older versions are kept
>   around.

Source: O'Reilly CouchDB The Definitive Guide, page 40.

Why is this? Because **CouchDB is not a version control system**: the versioning mechanism is there for concurrent access to the database. The Definitive Guide touches on this on pages 14-15.

Comment: +1, helpful answer although I *think* Chang understands that, he's just asking *before* compaction, when you click "previous version" in Futon, how can Couch fetch that document if it had been shadowed?

Comment: What is the point of the versioning system if you're not able to count on it? (I know this is an old question and I haven really googled to find an answer myself to this, but I'm tinking of including version control to a project. I've mostly thought about doing it in sql, but that might be a pain if you want to keep version of an entire object graph - object with subobjects. So I'm looking around)